# Scrapy Not Saving with AutoThrottle

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I can save data without autothrottle but when I turn it on I cannot save json data anymore.

Is there a solution using CrawlerProcess? Not sure if it's a bug or not.

**Update:**

Adding in all code.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):  
    name = None
    start_urls = None

class Spider:

    def __init__(self,parse,start_urls,**kwargs):
        self.name = 'spider'
        self.parse = parse      
        self.start_urls = start_urls
        self.kwargs = kwargs.get('settings')

    def run(self):

        process = CrawlerProcess(self.kwargs)
        MySpider.name = self.name
        MySpider.start_urls = self.start_urls
        MySpider.parse = self.parse     
        process.crawl(MySpider)
        process.start() 

FILE_NAME = 'my_data.json'

SETTINGS = {
            'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)',
            'FEED_FORMAT': 'json',
            'FEED_URI': FILE_NAME,
            'HTTPERROR_ALLOWED_CODES' : [x for x in range(200,600)],
            'AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED':True,
            'AUTOTHROTTLE_DEBUG':True,

            'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN':5,
            'DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT':5,

            'RANDOMIZE_DOWNLOAD_DELAY':True,            
            'DNS_TIMEOUT':5,}



def parse(self,response):
    yield {             
            'url': response.url,
            'status':response.status,
            'redirects': response.request.meta.get('redirect_urls'),
               }



s = Spider(parse=parse,       
           start_urls=START_URLS,
           settings=SETTINGS)
s.run()
```

I inherited the MySpider class so I could create a module out of the spider.

Comment: what do you mean by _"saving data"_?

Comment: Saving data is defined by the two params: `'FEED_FORMAT': 'json', 'FEED_URI': FILE_NAME`  There should be data saved to the json file but it's blank.

Comment: Please share your spider code too. I don't know if/how autothrottle can influence feed exports.

Comment: I added in the total code.